# LDAP authentication error in django

Tags: python, django, authentication, ldap, django-login

I am working on a django app and have to incorporate the LDAP authentication mechanism. Currently my files look like:

---settings.py

```
import ldap  
from django_auth_ldap.config import LDAPSearch    

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
        'django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend',
        'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = 'ip_address'
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN = 'cn=admin,dc=******,dc=com'
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = '*****'
AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearch("ou=Users,dc=*****,dc=com",ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,"(uid = (%Users))" )

AUTH_LDAP_ALWAYS_UPDATE_USER = True

AUTH_LDAP_USER_ATTR_MAP = {
       "first_name": "givenName",
       "last_name": "sh",
       "email": "mail" 
}

import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('django_auth_ldap')
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

----urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [    
    url(r'^info/$','django.contrib.auth.views.login',{'template_name': 'auth.html'}),
    url(r'^info/login/$',login),]
```

----auth.html

```
<html>
    <head>      
        <title>Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="login/" method="post">{%csrf_token%}
            Email address: <input type="text" name="email"/>
            Password: <input type="password" name="password" />
            <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

---- views.py

```
def login(request):  
     user = authenticate( username= request.REQUEST.get('email'), password= request.REQUEST.get('password')) #email and password supplied through auth.html  
     if user is not None:  
            return getInfo(request)
     else:
                return render(request,'invalidUser.html')
```

Currently I am using it on localhost for the testing purpose but LDAP ip_address in **AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI** is public for the company(i have taken this from the administrator). When i try to login, the errors that are thrown with same settings are:
1. Caught **LDAPError** while authenticating anshul: **LDAPError(0, 'Error')**
or
2. Caught **LDAPError** while authenticating anshul: **LDAPError(2, 'No such file or directory')**

My question is:
1. Why the error and meaning of 1st error? is it because of that access is not there for me at LDAP?
2. What is the purpose of

```
    import logging
    logger = logging.getLogger('django_auth_ldap')
    logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

In settings.py?

This is the first time i am working on django. Is it because of improper configuration or i cant access **AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI** through localhost and directly deploy on actual server with current settings?

Comment: In regards to `LDAPError(0, 'Error')`, on this line `AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = 'ip_address'`, you need to add `'ldap://ip_address'` hence it should be  `AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = 'ldap://ip_address'`

Answer (score 1):

[AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI](https://pythonhosted.org/django-auth-ldap/reference.html#auth-ldap-server-uri) is a URI, not a bare IP address. For example, `ldap://localhost/`. If you're not sure about a value, open a Python shell and test it:

```
> import ldap
> conn = ldap.initialize('ldap://<host-or-ip>/')
```

Also, [AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH](https://pythonhosted.org/django-auth-ldap/authentication.html#search-bind) should contain `%(user)s`, not `%(Users)`.

The logging configuration just hooks up the django_auth_ldap debug output to your console so that you'll see it. The default logging settings in Python/Django will just eat the output. These days, you can also set this up in Django's [LOGGING](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#logging) setting.